# act-dom.production.min.js:216 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map') at Li (Home.js:68:23)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, deployment, vercel

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Card from '../components/Card'
// import Carousel from '../components/Carousel'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
export default function Home() {
  const [foodCat, setFoodCat] = useState([])
  const [foodItems, setFoodItems] = useState([])
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const loadFoodItems = async () => {
    let response = await fetch("https://meal-express-backend.vercel.app/api/auth/foodData", {
      // credentials: 'include',
      // Origin:"http://localhost:3000/login",
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }

    });
    response = await response.json()
    // console.log(response[1][0].CategoryName)
    setFoodItems(response[0])
    setFoodCat(response[1])
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadFoodItems()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div >
      <div>
        <Navbar />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div id="carouselExampleFade" className="carousel slide carousel-fade " data-bs-ride="carousel">

          <div className="carousel-inner " id='carousel'>
            <div className=" carousel-caption  " style={{ zIndex: "9" }}>
              <div className=" d-flex justify-content-center">  {/* justify-content-center, copy this <form> from navbar for search box */}
                <input className="form-control me-2 w-75 bg-white text-dark" type="search" placeholder="Search in here..." aria-label="Search" value={search} onChange={(e) => { setSearch(e.target.value) }} />
                <button className="btn text-white bg-danger" onClick={() => { setSearch('') }}>X</button>
              </div >
            </div >
            <div className="carousel-item active" >
              <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x700/?burger" className="d-block w-100  " style={{ filter: "brightness(30%)" }} alt="..." />
            </div>
            <div className="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x700/?pastry" className="d-block w-100 " style={{ filter: "brightness(30%)" }} alt="..." />
            </div>
            <div className="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x700/?barbeque" className="d-block w-100 " style={{ filter: "brightness(30%)" }} alt="..." />
            </div>
          </div >
          <button className="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button className="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div >
      </div >
      <div className='container'> {/* boootstrap is mobile first */}
        {
          foodCat !== []
            ? foodCat.map((data) => {
              return (
                // justify-content-center
                <div className='row mb-3'>
                  <div key={data.id} className='fs-3 m-3'>
                    {data.CategoryName}
                  </div>
                  <hr id="hr-success" style={{ height: "4px", backgroundImage: "-webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgb(0, 255, 137),rgb(0, 0, 0))" }} />
                  {foodItems !== [] ? foodItems.filter(
                    (items) => (items.CategoryName === data.CategoryName) && (items.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())))
                    .map(filterItems => {
                      return (
                        <div key={filterItems.id} className='col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3'>
                          {console.log(filterItems.url)}
                          <Card foodName={filterItems.name} item={filterItems} options={filterItems.options[0]} ImgSrc={filterItems.img} ></Card>
                        </div>
                      )
                    }) : <div> No Such Data </div>}
                </div>
              )
            })
            : ""}
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div >
  )
}
```

Can Anyone fix the error...

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qSau.png)

Please fix this error whenever i opening my website https://meal-express-phda.vercel.app/ this error comes , fix the code and re write the corrected code…

Please fix this error whenever i opening my website https://meal-express-phda.vercel.app/ this error comes , fix the code and re write the corrected code…

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: https://github.com/Utkarsh-Jain2199/Meal-Express : My Github Link

Comment: `foodCat !== []` will always be `false`. Even if it worked you would get the same error, because `foodCat` is `null` and not empty array. `response[1]` that you assign to the `foodCat` is probably `null`

Comment: @Konrad hello bro can you tell what i have to change , i am a begginer in react

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `foodCat !== []` condition.
Try changing the condition to :

```
foodCat?.length ? foodCat.map((data) => {
              return (
                // justify-content-center
                <div className='row mb-3'>
                  <div key={data.id} className='fs-3 m-3'>
                    {data.CategoryName}
                  </div>
                  <hr id="hr-success" style={{ height: "4px", backgroundImage: "-webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgb(0, 255, 137),rgb(0, 0, 0))" }} />
                  {foodItems !== [] ? foodItems.filter(
                    (items) => (items.CategoryName === data.CategoryName) && (items.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())))
                    .map(filterItems => {
                      return (
                        <div key={filterItems.id} className='col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3'>
                          {console.log(filterItems.url)}
                          <Card foodName={filterItems.name} item={filterItems} options={filterItems.options[0]} ImgSrc={filterItems.img} ></Card>
                        </div>
                      )
                    }) : <div> No Such Data </div>}
                </div>
              )
            })
            : ""}
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: act-dom.production.min.js:216 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at Li (Home.js:68:19)
    at sa (react-dom.production.min.js:157:137)
    at Za (react-dom.production.min.js:180:154)
    at Ks (react-dom.production.min.js:269:343)
    at Pl (react-dom.production.min.js:250:347)
    at Tl (react-dom.production.min.js:250:278)
    at Ol (react-dom.production.min.js:250:138)
    at bl (react-dom.production.min.js:243:163)

Now getting this error